# Kafka spout bad performance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm testing simple topology to check kafka spout performance.
It contains kafka spout and Bolt that acknowledge each tuple.
Bolt execute method:

```java
public void execute(Tuple input) {
    collector.ack(input);
}
```

Topology looks like this:

```java
protected void configureTopology(TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder) {
    configureKafkaCDRSpout(topologyBuilder);
    configureKafkaSpoutBandwidthTesterBolt(topologyBuilder);
}

private void configureKafkaCDRSpout(TopologyBuilder builder) {
    KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(createKafkaCDRSpoutConfig());
    int spoutCount = Integer.valueOf(topologyConfig.getProperty("kafka.cboss.cdr.spout.thread.count"));
    builder.setSpout(KAFKA_CDR_SPOUT_ID, kafkaSpout, spoutCount)
            .setNumTasks(Integer.valueOf(topologyConfig.getProperty(KAFKA_CDR_SPOUT_NUM_TASKS)));
}
private SpoutConfig createKafkaCDRSpoutConfig() {
    BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(topologyConfig.getProperty("kafka.zookeeper.broker.host"));
    String topic = topologyConfig.getProperty("kafka.cboss.cdr.topic");
    String zkRoot = topologyConfig.getProperty("kafka.cboss.cdr.zkRoot");
    String consumerGroupId = topologyConfig.getProperty("kafka.cboss.cdr.consumerId");
    SpoutConfig kafkaSpoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, topic, zkRoot, consumerGroupId);
    kafkaSpoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new CbossCdrScheme());
    kafkaSpoutConfig.ignoreZkOffsets = true;
    kafkaSpoutConfig.fetchSizeBytes = Integer.valueOf(topologyConfig.getProperty("kafka.fetchSizeBytes"));
    kafkaSpoutConfig.bufferSizeBytes = Integer.valueOf(topologyConfig.getProperty("kafka.bufferSizeBytes"));
    return kafkaSpoutConfig;
}

public void configureKafkaSpoutBandwidthTesterBolt(TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder) {
    SimpleAckerBolt b = new SimpleAckerBolt();
    topologyBuilder.setBolt(SPOUT_BANDWIDTH_TESTER_BOLT_ID, b, Integer.valueOf(topologyConfig.getProperty(CFG_SIMPLE_ACKER_BOLT_PARALLELISM)))
            .setNumTasks(Integer.valueOf(topologyConfig.getProperty(SPOUT_BANDWIDTH_TESTER_BOLT_NUM_TASKS)))
            .localOrShuffleGrouping(KAFKA_CDR_SPOUT_ID);
}
```

Other topology settings:

```
topology.max.spout.pending=250
topology.executor.receive.buffer.size=1024
topology.executor.send.buffer.size=1024
topology.receiver.buffer.size=8
topology.transfer.buffer.size=1024
topology.acker.executors=1
```

I'm launching my topology with 1 worker 1 Kafka Spout and 1 Simple Acker Bolt.
Thats what i get in storm UI:
[image: Perfomance test 1]

Okey I got 1.5kk tuples in 10min. Bolts capasity is around 0,5. So my logic is simple: If i double spout and bolts parallelism hint - I will get double perfomance.
Next test was with 1 worker 2 Kafka Spout, 2 Simple Acker Bolt and topology.acker.executors=2. Here is results:

[image: Perfomance test 2]

So, I get worse perfomance with increased parallelizm hint. Why could it happend? How can I increse tuples per second processing? Actualy any test with spout parallelism hint greater than 2 shows worse result than 1 spout executor.

I've already checked:
1) It's not kafka fault. Topic have 20 partitions on 2 brokers. Topology on 4 workers scales and get x4 perfomance.
2) It's not server fault.  Server has 40 cores and 32Gb RAM. While runing topology it consumes around 1/8 CPU and almost none RAM.
3) Changing topology.max.spout.pending paramter doesn't help.
4) Increasing Bolt or Acker parallelism hint even more doesn't help.

Comment: You ran both tests with only one worker, what if you added another worker? So run the second test with two workers.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Morgan. You right. Increasing number of workers give me proportional result. With 2 workers 2 spouts I have double my tuples per second. But idea of this tests to mesure best perfomance of 1 worker. And the best I can get is 1,5kk tuples per 10 min, or 2500 tuples per second. I guess on node with 40 cores, 32GB RAM and 10Gb/s network I can do better.

Comment: 1 worker but 40 cores doesn't really make sense. Every worker is a single thread anyway, so it means your server has the capacity to host 40 workers. You'd have the exact same perf on a single core server right now. And 2500 tuples/s per thread isn't exactly great, but still not too bad either.

Comment: Storm documentation says that 1 worker is 1 JVM. So theres no reason to run multiple workers on 1 node.

Comment: @f1sherox, I wouldn't necessarily agree with that statement. One reason to run multiple workers is for more fault tolerance. If you only have 1 worker, if that 1 worker fails your entire topology fails. If you have 6 workers, and 1 worker fails, 5 workers are still running. Also, a worker can only belong to one topology, so only having 1 worker means your Storm cluster can only support 1 topology at a time.

Comment: Good point. Didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems as though you're hitting a limit with your performance of one worker. You're just giving the one worker to much to do and it can't handle it all.

At this point if you want to further increase the performance of your system you have two options.

1. Add more workers.
2. Improve your one workers ability to perform work.

If you do not want to add more workers, then what is left to you is to configure your one worker. You should then investigate the configuration for your one worker to give it more memory, more cpu, etc. You should probably look over the [default configuration options](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml) for Storm and see whether tweaking some configuration values gives you better performance. Some of the configs that seem more likely to help than others:

```
worker.heap.memory.mb:
worker.childopts:
supervisor.childopts:
supervisor.memory.capacity.mb:
supervisor.cpu.capacity:
```

Comment: I've tried to increase heap size of worker and supervisor but still nothing changes. Settings I've changed: supervisor.childopts, worker.childopts. Also I've tried to change this settings:topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size, topology.worker.receiver.thread.count. Here full config http://pastebin.com/TEB6d3Ve

Comment: I've never really done much Storm optimization, so I can't help much on that front. But unless you have a valid reason not to I would recommend increasing the number of workers to gain better performance.